# ionic 3 directive styling

Tags: css, ionic-framework, styles, ionic3

Hi I'm currently at ionic 3.12.1 and I wanted to ask if there was any possibilities to style a directive directly.
If I add css classes to the directives the css class won't even show up.

```
<ion-list class="tracker-list">
        <ion-list-header class="tracker-header">
            Action
        </ion-list-header>
        <ion-item>Terminator II</ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You best approach would be to look into [ionic sass variables](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/)

In your example you would target the `ion-list` variables in your `theme/variables.scss` file REF: [list variables](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/list/List/#sass-variables)

What you might need to do in order to get your current classes working is to wrap the classes in the 3 modes

```
.md,.wp,.ios{
 .tracker-list{
 }
 .tracker-header{
  }
}
```

That tells iconic that your classes are more important then ionic's predefined classes.